# React-Native navigate between pages

Tags: react-native, navigation

I'm making a simple, 2 static pages app in React-Native.

There will be a Landing Page with a button (TouchableHighlight) `About us` and when a user clicks on it, it should render a totally new component.

In html it would be done with something like this: `<a href="aboutus.html">`

I have tried to use `react-native-router-flux` but I keep getting some errors and I don't want to have a header.

Comment: I would recommend using [react-navigation](https://github.com/react-community/react-navigation) for this purpose.  I have used it for several of my apps.

Comment: Can you post your router code and errors please ?

Answer (score 0):

I do it this way

In index.android.js (index.js), you import and define screen you want to navigate

```
    import {StackNavigator} from 'react-navigation'
    import App from './App';
    import App1 from './App1';
    import App2 from './App2';

    const Navigation = StackNavigator({
        App:{screen: App},
        App1:{screen: App1},
        App2:{screen: App2}
    });
```

In your screen you want to navigate here is App.js

```
export default class App extends React.Component<{}> {
        static navigationOptions={
            title:'First Screen',
        }
      render() {
        var {navigate} = this.props.navigation;
        return (
          <View>
            <Text>This is first screen</Text>
            <Button
                onPress={() => navigate('App1')}
                title="Go to screen 2"
            />
          </View>
        );
      }
    }
```

App1.js  will same as App.js if you want to navigate to another (App2.js)

Comment: everytime I install that library (`react-navigation`) I get some random issues. Don't know why but it breaks the project